# Issue with NextJS: Invariant failed: provided.innerRef has not been provided with a HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-beautiful-dnd

Issue with React Frameworks?

I am using latest version of React & NextJS. I tried to debug my code a lot by reading through your actual guide and stack overflow.

I was trying to test out the feature in plain vanilla React first where the vertical sorting list worked smoothly but the moment I switched to NextJS and implemented the same functionality I get this particular error.

```
next-dev.js?3515:20 react-beautiful-dndA setup problem was encountered.> Invariant failed: provided.innerRef has not been provided with a HTMLElement.You can find a guide on using the innerRef callback functions at:https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/using-inner-ref.md‍ This is a development only message. It will be removed in production builds.
```

In the recommended guide, it has been clearly mentioned that the reference should be to an actual DOM element not a component which is what is exactly in my scenario!
But still my code is not working!

My structure of code is as followes:

Index.js (entry point)
Column.js (A component that gets called in Index.js)

**1. Index.js**

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Column = dynamic(() => import('../src/Column'), { ssr: false });

const initialData = {
  tasks: [
    { id: 1, content: 'The first task' },
    { id: 2, content: 'The second task' },
    { id: 3, content: 'The third task' },
    { id: 4, content: 'The fourth task' },
    { id: 5, content: 'The fifth task' },
  ],
};

export default function Home() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialData);

  return (
    <DragDropContext>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          background: '#0E1012',
          minHeight: '100vh',
          width: '100%',
          color: '"#E8E8EA',
          paddingBottom: '2rem',
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            paddingTop: '4rem',
            paddingBottom: '4rem',
          }}
        >
          <h2 style={{ fontsize: '1.875rem' }}>react-beautiful-dnd</h2>
          <p style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: '#9B9B9B' }}></p>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            paddingInlineStart: '4rem',
          }}
        >
          <Column tasks={state.tasks} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}
```

**2. Column.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Column = ({ tasks }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          borderRadius: '3px',
          background: '#16181D',
          width: '500px',
          height: '610px',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          position: 'relative',
        }}
      >
        <Droppable droppableId='col'>
          {(droppableProvided) => {
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  padding: '1.5rem',
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  flex: '1',
                }}
                {...droppableProvided.droppableProps}
                ref={droppableProvided.innerRef}
              >
                {tasks.map((task, index) => {
                  return (
                    <Draggable
                      key={task.id}
                      draggableId={task.id.toString()}
                      index={index}
                    >
                      {(draggableProvided, draggableSnapshot) => {
                        <div
                          style={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            marginBottom: '1rem',
                            height: '100px',
                            background: '#242731',
                            borderRadius: '3px',
                            padding: '1.5rem',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            '&:active': {
                              background: '#23252f',
                            },
                          }}
                          {...draggableProvided.dragHandleProps}
                          {...draggableProvided.draggableProps}
                          ref={draggableProvided.innerRef}
                        >
                          <p style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>{task.content}</p>
                        </div>;
                      }}
                    </Draggable>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Droppable>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Column;
```

**and finally my package.json looks like this**

```
{
  "name": "dnd",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1"
  }
}
```

Despite going through the guide by the team of react-beautiful-dnd for the exact same issue, my bug remains unresolved!

As you can see I am calling `ref={provided.innerRef}` on the ReactElement and not a component!

Where am I going wrong?

Is this an issue of Class based Components vs Function based Component declaration?